# Change cursor color on key press in emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to change my cursor color when i am pressing backspace, but it still should delete backward char and then if i press any key(except backspace) color should be changed back to what it was before change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a weird request, but, just to demonstrate the awesome powers of
Emacs, I will do it for you:

```
(defvar cursor-color-original nil
  "The original cursor color, saved while backspacing.")
(defvar cursor-color-while-backspace "Red"
  "The cursor color while backspacing.")
(defvar cursor-color-backspace-commands
  '(backward-delete-char-untabify delete-backward-char)
  "The commands that switch cursor color.")
(defvar cursor-color-backspace-keys
  (list (kbd "<DEL>"))
  "The keys that switch cursor color.")

(defun cursor-color-note-backspace ()
  "Switch cursor color when backspacing."
  (if (or (memq this-command cursor-color-backspace-commands)
          (member (this-command-keys) cursor-color-backspace-keys))
      (unless (equal (frame-parameter nil 'cursor-color)
                     cursor-color-after-backspace)
        (setq original-cursor-color (frame-parameter nil 'cursor-color))
        (set-cursor-color cursor-color-after-backspace))
    (when (equal (frame-parameter nil 'cursor-color)
                 cursor-color-after-backspace)
      (set-cursor-color original-cursor-color))))
```

To enable:

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'cursor-color-note-backspace)
```

To disable:

```
(remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'cursor-color-note-backspace)
```

Note that if this does not work for you, you should do <kbd>C-h c DEL</kbd> and add the function called by `DEL` to the `cursor-color-backspace-commands`.
You can also add keys to `cursor-color-backspace-keys`.

Happy hacking!

PS. Please do <kbd>C-h f RET</kbd> on every function that you do not know. This will help you write such a snippet yourself next time.